# Amazon S3 configuration always returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup a secured access to one of my bucket, and I can't make it work, even though I'm pretty sure everything is fine.

I have this bucket, let's call it `mybucket` that I created in Ireland.
It contains two folders, `dev` and `prod`.

I created two users:

- `mybucket-prod`, ARN : `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-prod`
- `mybucket-dev`, ARN : `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-dev`

Each of these users have a policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439909068000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(and the same for **mybucket-prod**, who has Resource = `"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/prod/*"`)

And here's the bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1439908568053",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439908459631",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-dev"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/dev/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439908500795",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-prod"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/prod/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I can't make it work, for both users. I tried creating a new access key, without any luck too.

What did I do wrong?

Maybe it's worth noticing that I copied the content of an other bucket to this one, by going on the web interface of Amazon, clicking on "dev" and "prod" from the previous bucket, selecting "copy", then going `mybucket` and selecting "paste"?

I also tried the policy simulator and the result was positive (allowed).

I'm using `boto` (Python), but as I said, I didn't changed anything in the code and the error occurs since I changed the bucket name. I tested with a really basic code, that returns the same error :

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

con = S3Connection('KEY', 'SECRET', host='s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')

print Key(bucket=con.get_bucket('mybucket'), name="/prod/2/documents/1-demo.pdf")
```

And I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print Key(bucket=con.get_bucket('mybucket'), name="/prod/2/contracts/1/documents/1-cillit.pdf")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 502, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 535, in head_bucket
    raise err
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: could you elaborate "can't make it work"? are you not able to for example put an object to those buckets with those IAM users' credentials?

Comment: Yes exactly : I can't read an object nor put an object (didn't really tested the delete, I didn't come that far). I always get a 403 error.

Comment: In case it would help, I use `boto` (Python), and the code was working well before I changed my bucket. The whole reason was to rename the bucket to an other name.

Comment: you need to show a simple example of the boto code that does not work

Comment: The simplest solution is to start by allowing all actions so that you aren't troubleshooting bucket policy when you have a second, unrelated problem.  Also be sure you're examining the response body from S3.  Most 403 errors don't give you hints in the response body, but some do.

Comment: @Vorsprung As I said, I didn't changed anything in the code so adding an example won't change the situation. But I still added a really basic code that yield the same error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Is there a basic "allow all" rule to test ?

Comment: Is it redondant to specify a policy to an user AND a bucket policy? Shouldn't I make just one (either bucket policy or user policy)?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution after hours of searching.

@Michael-sqlbot put me on the right track by extending the authorization.

Turns out, I needed to add one extra permission to make everything works (I don't know why it worked before though!).

Here's the new bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1439908568053",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1439972574242",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-dev",
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-prod"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439908459631",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-dev"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/dev/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439908500795",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/mybucket-prod"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/prod/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The new permission is to add "ListBucket" to the bucket, for the users that will connect to it (`mybucket-dev` and `mybucket-prod`). When adding this new permission, everything worked just fine.

I also deleted the policy attached to the users.

I'm curious to know if what I did is correct or if I did something wrong (is the permission "ListBucket" not too wide? is removing the user's policy correct?)

But well, now it works!